# How to insert current date into MySQL database use Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I want to insert the current date and time into a columns defined as datetime type.

I typed the following code:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
PrepStmt.setDate(1, sqlDate);
```

When I check the database, I find that the date inserted correctly, but the time is: 00:00:00. What is the fix ?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column in your MySQL database?

Comment: @doublesharp. He has written there. Its datetime.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since you are using `datetime` as your column type, you need to use `java.sql.Timestamp` to store your date, and `PrepareStatement.setTimestamp` to insert it.

Try using this: -

```
java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
PrepStmt.setTimestamp(1, date);
```

Answer (score 9):

You are using wrong method. You can use [`PreparedStatement#setTimestamp(int parameterIndex,
                  Timestamp x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29) instead.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to use is the [setTimestamp(int parameterIndex,Timestamp x)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29) method instead of the setDate() method.

One of the ways you can set the timestamp would be as follows:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
```

You can then set the parameter as:

```
PrepStmt.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need

```
java.sql.Timestamp
```

The one that your using `java.sql.Date` is for dealing with dates only and does not record time. Alternatively you can use `java.sql.Time` if you do want time only.

Answer (score 2):

Try with setTimestamp as

```
PrepStmt.setTimestamp(1, sqlDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
PrepStmt.setTimestamp(1, date);
```

I solved it using this..